# How to handle irregular time intervals in CnosDB？

Tags: cnosdb

I'm using a time-series database to manage my time-series data, but I've noticed that there are some irregular time intervals in my data, which has been causing me confusion when working with it. At times, the time intervals between data points might vary, and I would like to efficiently handle them during queries and analysis.

I'm wondering if there are specific techniques or strategies to deal with this type of data in a time-series database. Are there methods to standardize time intervals or perform effective queries and aggregation operations in cases of irregular time intervals?